# My fetch doesn't upload the JSON string, I can't see the error in my code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch, slim

I'm using Slim v4 for my REST API for testing purposes.

I want to fetch a JSON Data string to my REST API for saving some events.

```
    public async callSaveEvent(event: EventList) {
        let url: string = config.basePath + "eventList/saveEventList";
        console.table(JSON.stringify(event));
        await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ event })

        }).then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("Something is bad");
            }

        }).catch(error => {
            console.error("Das ist passiert!: ", error);
        });

    }
```

This is my current Code. If I use the fetch.options.mode == "cors", I recieve in Slim that this Method is not allowed. Method is OPTIONS instead of POST. Because of this I using mode == "no-cors".

```
        $param = $req->getParsedBody();
        $param_ = $param;
        $resp->getBody()->write($param);
        return $resp;
    }
```

This is my Backend Code. When I try to read the parsedBody, its just empty.

If I send a request with PostMan its accept the data and I get the data in the $param variable.

Can someone find some errors? I can't find them.